# Compact asymmetric form in the plane?

Tags: compactness, plane-geometry, symmetry, plane-curves

Not being a mathematician, I may be imprecise in asking my question. For experiments on the visual perception of symmetries in the plane, I'm looking for (a) a closed curve in the plane, that is (b) asymmetric (wrt rotation and reflection), and is (c) compact  (as close as possible to the compactness of a circle), (d) minimizes points of inflexion. I thought that perhaps a half yin-yang would be a suitable candidate, but the question seems underdetermined.

Comment: What do you mean by "compact"? To a mathematician, every closed curve in the plane is compact :)

Comment: More compact = lower curve length/area covered, The circle being the most compact in that sense.

Comment: It seems you're looking for small perturbations of a circle. There shouldn't be one that achieves the best (area enclosed)/length, by the proof of the isoperimetric inequality.

Comment: @ronno : small perturbations of a circle wouldn't satisfy the needs of a psychological experiment. The form needs to be visibly different from a circle, be as smooth as possible. The yin only has one point of inflexion and a discontinuity in the derivative. It also looks as asymmetric as any form I've seen.